# Changing the name of my app?

Tags: xcode

How do I change the name of my app within Xcode 6, so that it will change the name of all of my files properly?

Answer (score 0):

select your target under "Targets" in the project editor, then choose View > Utilities > Show File Inspector. Xcode opens the File inspector, which includes the Identity and Type pane. Enter your application's new name in the Project Name field then hit the return key on your keyboard.

Xcode displays a project-rename dialog that contains all the items that can be renamed in your project. Leave your application selected in the dialog and deselect all other items then click Rename to perform the rename operation.

Hope this helps